# How to center a inline form bootstrap 3

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am trying to make a search bar with multiple options and want to center it

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<div id="search_panel">
  <div class='container'>
    <form class="form-inline" role="form">
      <!-- SEARCH PLACE -->
      <div class="form-group">
        <label class="sr-only" for="inputEmail">search</label>
        <input id="where" name="where" type="search" placeholder="where you want to visit ...." class="form-control input-md" required="">
      </div>
      <!-- CHECK-IN DATE -->
      <div class="form-group" id="start">
        <i class="fa fa-calendar fa-2x"></i>
        <input type='text' placeholder="Check-In Date" class="form-control" id='datepicker-start' />
      </div>
      <div class="form-group" id="end">
        <i class="fa fa-calendar fa-2x"></i>
        <input type='text' placeholder="Check-Out Date" class="form-control" id='datepicker-end' />
      </div>
      <!-- Button Drop Down -->
      <div class="form-group">
        <label class="sr-only" for="inputEmail">Select Basic</label>
        <select id="selectbasic" name="selectbasic" class="form-control">
          <option value="1">Option one</option>
          <option value="2">Option two</option>
        </select>
      </div>
    </form>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: It's very difficult to tell what your question is. Could you please try to explain more closely what you are trying to achieve.

Answer (score 14):

you can also combine classes

if you change your defnition from

```
<form class="form-inline" role="form">
```

to
 `<form class="form-inline text-center" role="form">`
it should work!

Id like to keep as much as I can plain bootstrap before I add extra styles

and bootstrap comes with native alignment classes which can be found here: http://getbootstrap.com/css/#type-alignment

HTH

Comment: Keeping as much as possible plain bootstrap before adding custom styles is exactly the purpose of the framework/library. +1 for the simplicity.

Answer (score 7):

I would try adding `text-align: center` to the form.  See my example (note that to see the effect, you have to select "Full page".  Otherwise, bootsrap defaults to mobile view).

### Edit:

oops! I guess you don't need `inline-block`.  I had it as `inline-bock` anyway. :P

```css
#search_panel {
    text-align: center; 
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<div id="search_panel">
  <div class='container'>
    <form class="form-inline" role="form">
      <!-- SEARCH PLACE -->
      <div class="form-group">
        <label class="sr-only" for="inputEmail">search</label>
        <input id="where" name="where" type="search" placeholder="where you want to visit ...." class="form-control input-md" required="">
      </div>
      <!-- CHECK-IN DATE -->
      <div class="form-group" id="start">
        <i class="fa fa-calendar fa-2x"></i>
        <input type='text' placeholder="Check-In Date" class="form-control" id='datepicker-start' />
      </div>
      <div class="form-group" id="end">
        <i class="fa fa-calendar fa-2x"></i>
        <input type='text' placeholder="Check-Out Date" class="form-control" id='datepicker-end' />
      </div>
      <!-- Button Drop Down -->
      <div class="form-group">
        <label class="sr-only" for="inputEmail">Select Basic</label>
        <select id="selectbasic" name="selectbasic" class="form-control">
          <option value="1">Option one</option>
          <option value="2">Option two</option>
        </select>
      </div>
    </form>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: it works but when i add position:absolute; to #search_panel it floats to left
what I am trying to do is overlay this #social panel on another div

Answer (score 3):

Simply add the **.text-center** class to the row that holds that form

```html
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN"
    "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" lang="en">
  <head>
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8" />
<meta charset="utf-8">
<!-- meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" -->
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<!-- The above 3 meta tags *must* come first in the head; any other head content must come *after* these tags -->
<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-1q8mTJOASx8j1Au+a5WDVnPi2lkFfwwEAa8hDDdjZlpLegxhjVME1fgjWPGmkzs7" crossorigin="anonymous">

<!-- Optional theme -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" integrity="sha384-fLW2N01lMqjakBkx3l/M9EahuwpSfeNvV63J5ezn3uZzapT0u7EYsXMjQV+0En5r" crossorigin="anonymous">

<!-- HTML5 shim and Respond.js for IE8 support of HTML5 elements and media queries -->
<!-- WARNING: Respond.js doesn't work if you view the page via file:// -->
<!--[if lt IE 9]>
  <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/html5shiv/3.7.2/html5shiv.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/respond/1.4.2/respond.min.js"></script>
<![endif]-->
  </head>
  <body>
<div class="container-fluid" style="background-color: #EEEEEE;">
  <div class="row text-center">
    <div class="col-sm-12" id="formContainer">
      <form class="form-inline" id="SignToNewsletterForm" onsubmit="...">
        <input type="text" class="form-control input-lg" id="firstname" placeholder="Your first name...">
        <input type="email" class="form-control input-lg" id="email" placeholder="Your Email Address...">
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success btn-lg">I Want To Subscribe</button>
      </form>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if I've understood your question but here is an example of centering the form:

http://jsfiddle.net/Lfw3v0p6/

I simply added some CSS:

```
.form-inline {
    text-align: center;
}
```

If this is not what you're looking for, please update your question to provide more details or an example of what you have tried.

Answer (score 0):

```
#search_panel {
    text-align: center; 
    z-index:10;
    position:absolute;
    padding-left:5%;
    top:40%;
}
```

I worked out by giving a left padding cause when position is absolute all padding is gone